# Flutter provider not working in release apk, but working fine in debug mode

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

the provider should work to provide real time updates to consumers but only works in debug mode and not release mode. do i have to use the state full widget again to update the ui with set state, any clue?

Comment: please provide more information about your problem.some piece of your code could help much more

Comment: We'll need more information to be able to help you. You must be doing something wrong because "it works for me." So try and create the smallest test case that fails. You may be lucky and find your error when doing that, and if not, we can help.

Comment: Did you find any solution of this? I am also facing problem, Provider is working in debug mode but in release mode API is calling perfectly still provider not notifying UI.

I already have Internet permission and API is calling perfectly fine.

Answer (score 10):

Might be possible that you missed to add internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

We have to add Internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file for release build. It is working fine in debug mode. If you have been calling api call in provider. Same mistake I have done and resolved that issue.

Comment: Ran into this issue recently. Good tip

Comment: thanks man! I had a similar issuer and it helped me.
I'm begining in flutter, and there is actually 2 androidManifest.xml : one in app/src/main and one in app/src/profile
After adding the permission in the one located in app/src/main it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

If you add in the 2 AndroidManifest.xml files the internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and it is still not works, so add this in the 2 files in the **application** tag

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: what did you mean by in the 2 "files" in the application tag, I only see activity and meta-data tags in application tag

Comment: the 2 AndroidManifest.xml files