# Flutter (web) Provider not working in released mode, but working in debug

Tags: dart, provider, flutter-web

I'm experiencing some odd behavior where a Provider behaves differently in debug vs. release mode.

This question is posted in off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888106/flutter-provider-not-working-in-release-apk-but-working-fine-in-debug-mode#new-answer).

Here is a short description of the functionality: I have a list of ExpansionTiles (containing TextFormFields in their body) and a FloatingActionButton that adds to the list of ExpansionTiles. Below those two widgets I have one Back button and one Next button. The Next button needs be "unavailable" (ie. throw an error message to the user and have the color grey) as long as any TextFormField in the list of ExpansionTiles is incomplete. Once all TextFormFields are ready the Next button should change color and direct the user to a new page. Changing the color and functionality works fine in debug, but not in release mode (ie. after running: flutter build web).

Firstly: TravelProceedModel monitors the status of whether the user can click the Next button or not. Ie. this is just a simple bool. Whenever updateCanProceed() is called I update canProceed and also notifyListeners().

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TravelProceedModel extends ChangeNotifier {

  bool canProceed;

  void updateCanProceed(bool value) {

    canProceed = value;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Secondly, the TravelProceedModel is implemented using the ChangeNotifierProvider and then using Consumer. I'm expecting (and this works in debug) that when canProceed is changed this line: "nextEnabled: proceedModel.canProceed" should cause the button the change color. However, this only works in debug mode.

```
class TravelDeductionTrips extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TravelDeductionTripsState createState() => _TravelDeductionTripsState();
}

class _TravelDeductionTripsState extends State<TravelDeductionTrips> {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  String year = Provider.of<UserSelectionsModel>.(context).selected_report["year"];
  String report = Provider.of<UserSelectionsModel>(context).selected_report["report"];

  return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
     ChangeNotifierProvider(
       create: (context) => TravelProceedModel()
     ),
     ChangeNotifierProvider(
       create: (context) => TravelModel(
         year: year,
         report: report,
       ),
     ),
    ],
    child: Consumer<TravelModel>(
      builder: (context, travelModel, child) {
       return FutureBuilder(
         future: travelModel.fetchTripsToLocalSession(),
         builder: (context, data) {
           if (data.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
             return Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 TravelDeductionTripList(),
                 Consumer<TravelProceedModel>(
                   builder: (context, proceedModel, child) {
                     proceedModel.updateCanProceed(
                       travelModel.checkProceedCondition()
                     );
                     return BackNextButtons(
                       backEnabled: true,
                       nextEnabled: proceedModel.canProceed,
                       backText: "Tilbage",
                       nextText: travelModel.trips["next_action_title"],
                       errorMessage: travelModel.proceedErrorMessage,
                       nextFunction: () async {
                         await addQuestionIDtoStack(year, report, travelModel.trips["next_question_id"], true);
                       }, // No special function is needed, this is just a simple next
                     );
                   },
                 ),
               ],
             );
           } else {
             return Center(
               child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
             );
           }
         }
      );
    }
  ),
);
}
}
```

NB! proceedModel.canProceed is updated from within TravelDeductionTripList() which calls

```
Provider.of<TravelProceedModel>(context, listen: false).updateCanProceed(
  Provider.of<TravelModel>(context, listen: false).checkProceedCondition()
);
```

The Next button only changes colors after reloading the widget. Ie. it appears that the TravelProceedModel is being updated but that the widget is not being redrawn in the UI - although it happens perfectly in debug mode.

Does anybody have any idea why debug works but release does not?

Below is my "flutter doctor -v". Notice, that this is a flutter web project.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.15.17, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.15.17 at /Users/danni/Documents/flutter/flutter
    • Framework revision 2294d75bfa (13 days ago), 2020-03-07 00:28:38 +0900
    • Engine revision 5aff311948
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.12.0 9983424a3c)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/danni/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods installed but not working.
        You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
        This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used
        to invoke it.
        This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods. For more info, see
        https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14293.
      To re-install CocoaPods, run:
        sudo gem install cocoapods

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 41.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.43.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 80.0.3987.149
    • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and I've made a workaround for it.

Since `listen` is a parameter, you can pass any other bool variable to it (should not be a constant true or false).

There is a built-in bool variable in `foundation.dart` package called [kReleaseMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kReleaseMode-constant.html).

So here is an example, how i handled this listener problem between debug and release mode:

```
await Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: kReleaseMode).loginUser(
                  user: _username, password: _password);
```

For me, it works perfectly.

Comment: I have the same problem and I try this solution but doesn't work, for me.